# Link requirements within PDF or HTML files to increase traceability

Tags: agile, software-development, pm-software, requirements, redmine

Do you know of any tool (or plugin for such tool) with following features:

- Manage Requirements (like Redmine, DOORS, Borland Caliber and many more...)
- Link Requirements with parts of a PDF or HTML file (not linking the file itself, but linking stuff within the file)

*Examples for the files*

- Diagrams like an overview for customer (PDF)
- Wireframes of the UI (PDF)
- Webpages of the web application at certain stages of development (for customer reviews at milestone meetings) (HTML)

I have seen in DOORS the ability to link methods in C++ code with Requirements. *They're saying, that enables high traceability.* So, maybe there is something similar for a more "visual linking".

I am also fine with experimental/scientific tools or just clues where to research harder.

**Update** So far I found [BugHerd](http://bugherd.com), which is a webservice that offers flagging parts of HTML pages. BugHerd flags can be [synced with redmine](http://support.bugherd.com/entries/20419122-redmine) via a plugin.  I haven't tried it yet.

**Update 2** [BugHerd alternatives](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10518/let-tester-directly-click-on-web-site-to-report-bugs-similar-to-bugherd). However, the tools discussed there are more focused on tracking bugs with a nice on webpage screenshot editor.

Comment: This is only part of your question, but there is a StackOverflow question related to the technical details of linking to part of a PDF file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328653

Comment: Have a look at Visual Paradigm - it's a UML Modeling tool with in built support for requirements handling and "visual" connectivity you seek - that can be exported as Word/PDF etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

Any requirements management system - professional or adhoc - should be able to link to specific HTML pages using anchors and do the same for PDF files hosted via web server. E.g., [Page 3 Requirement](http://www.yoursite.com/file.pdf#page=3)

Hope that helps